# Can not post the nested object json to node express body parser

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, body-parser

Hi I'm creating sample REST api using Node, Express and Mongo. I'm using bodyParser() middle ware to parse the form data. Its working fine for simple object say

```
         var user = {
             name:'test',
             age:'20'
         }
```

**req.body** produce the same set of format to save it in the mongodb like.

```
         {
             name:'test',
             age:'20'
         }
```

When using complex object

```
         var user = {
                 name:'test',
                 age:'20',
                 education: {
                     institute:"xxx",
                     year:2010
                 }
            }
```

**req.body** produce different format something like

```
           {
                 name:'test',
                 age:'20',
                 education[institute]: "xxx",
                 edcuation[year]:2010
            }
```

I would like to get the same format which i post in the body to save them in the database. Is this the right approach or any other method available to this?

Answer (score 9):

I think it's not clear in the documentation. I've spent hours trying to find it. Anyway...

You need to change your body-parser option to `extended: true` as shown below.

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserurlencodedoptions

Comment: Actually, I may be having a similar [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38195552/trouble-with-posting-json-data-with-node-request-to-express-server-for-saving). Server is written in node.js + Express and client is another node.js app. The schema for the collection is hierarchical and thereby a bit more complex. I tried both `extended:true` and `extended:false` and neither work. What am I missing?

Comment: I really don't know why. But I recommend you to open a new question on stack or report on github site of body-parser.