# Mongodb inserting json from http.post into collection changes the json

Tags: json, mongodb, body-parser

I'm making an admin page for my mobile app using mongodb, nodejs etc. I'm  trying to insert an existing json file into mongodb collection. I tried mongoimport but it just didn't work (I read through and tried several stackoverflow discussions about it). So I figured out I can send it via http POST and use insert().

I've three localhost servers running: mongodb, app server and website adminpage

json file looks like:

```
{"data_version":1,"drivers_teams":{"drivers":{"4":{"name":"Hofer","firstname": ... }}}
```

client POST

```
    $.getJSON("initialData.json", function(json) {
            $.ajax({
              url: 'localhost:3080/client_data',
              type: 'POST',
              data: json,
              success: function(res) {
                console.log(res);
              }.bind(this),
              error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(url, status, err.toString());
              }.bind(this)
            });
    }.bind(this));
```

server POST

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '1000kb', parameterLimit: 5000}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '1000kb', parameterLimit: 5000, extended: false}));

    app.post('/client_data/', (req, res) => {
      const db = req.db;
      const collection = db.get('collection');

      collection.insert(req.body, function (err, doc) { 
            if (err) {
              res.status(500).send('Invalid request');
              return;
            }  
            res.send('ok');
      });
    });
```

so far so good, but after I manage to insert data and ask server what you got?  I get:

```
{"_id":"57872f9fe51246dc1b3bbc93","data_version":"1","drivers_teams[drivers][4][name]":"Hofer","drivers_teams[drivers][4][firstname] ... }}}
```

I can't use this data anymore. So question: How can I insert nested json as-is when it comes from http request body?

**EDIT**

Ok, figured out how to do the AS-IS insert(). Instead of http.post I load the json directly into collection;

server

```
import mydata from './initialData.json';

...

collection.insert(mydata, function (err, doc) { ... });
```

Still confused what I'm doing wrong with the request body. Because now if I make collection.update(); from client the updated element is obviously messed up with bracket notation thing.

Comment: Are you seeing the key attributes with square brackets in mongodb I.e the last json in your question?

Comment: Do you use some middlewares in express like bodyParser?

Comment: yes, app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '1000kb', parameterLimit: 5000}));

Comment: ok, it's the body-parser, here's the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26711666/can-not-post-the-nested-object-json-to-node-express-body-parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to change url encoded bodyParser options

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

this was really counter-intuitive, for me at least, because I was looking problem related to json, not forms...
Only backside is that everything is a string instead of their true type, but I don't care anymore once I'm this far.

**EDIT**

To get the data types right at the server-end I needed to JSON.stringify(data) and add contentType: 'application/json' in POST options

```
    post: function(data) {      
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function(res) {
                console.log(res)
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
```